# Add a square background to a radio button

Tags: radio-button, background-color

I'm probably missing something simple but here goes.

I have several radio buttons on my form and I want each one to have a square background only a few pixels larger than the button itself. As well I would like the inside of the button the same color as the background.

I tried using CSS to just change the background color of the radio button itself:

```
.Blue{
   background: blue;
}

<input type="radio" class="Blue" value="1"/>
```

But there is no styling of any kind with this.

Is it as simple as adding a `<div>` tag around each or is there another way of styling the radio input without extra tags?

Explanation for the Curious:
The colors represent moods and will have a tooltip when hovered.

Comment: Well I tried the <div> tag around each and that is what works. From reading around google the radio button is just the button itself and doesn't have background that can be styled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment above says the radio button input is only the button itself and doesn't have a background to style. To solve this I added a `<div>` around each and styled the `<div>` to suit my needs.